# Add all changes in new created branch also

Tags: git

Currently, I working on Staging Branch which is available in Master.
all my changed available in master and Staging right now. I have also created one additional Integration new branch in master at the beginning.I have not used this branch from starting so it has a fresh copy.

Now I just need to copy all my staging branch changes in my New branch.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried checking out the Integration branch and then merging master into it?

Comment: @evolutionxbox , are you talking about 
git checkout -b integration ?

Comment: That creates a new branch from whatever commit you’re on. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: git checkout -b integration   after using this, is it replace all my staging data with fresh copy ?

Comment: integration branch is already created on git . i need to all staging branch changes into integration branch.

Comment: So merge staging into integration?

Comment: change to your integration branch. merge your changes from master into your stating brach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have also created one additional Integration new branch in master at beginning

So Integration does not start from the current `master` HEAD, but from an older commit in `master`.

> I have not used this branch from staging, so it have fresh copy.

If it was not yet pushed:

```
git checkout integration
git reset --hard master
```

> I need to all staging branch changes into integration branch.

```
git merge staging
```